# Как сделать добавление нескольких фото при создании нового товара в боте тг?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram, бот

```
@admin.callback_query(AdminProtect(), AddItem.category)
async def add_item_category(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(category=callback.data.split('_')[1])
    await state.set_state(AddItem.description)
    await callback.answer('')
    await callback.message.answer('Введите описание товара')


@admin.message(AdminProtect(), AddItem.description)
async def add_item_description(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(description=message.text)
    await state.set_state(AddItem.photo)
    await message.answer('Отправьте фото товара')


@admin.message(AdminProtect(), AddItem.photo, F.photo)
async def add_item_photo(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(photo=message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await state.set_state(AddItem.price)
    await message.answer('Введите цену товара')
```

Это фрагмент кода отвечающего за добавление товара прямо в боте, чтобы не лезть в базу данных
Пока что он принимает только 1 фото, хотелось бы реализовать добавление 3 фото. Сделать это на примере бот ДайВинчика, где при заполнении анкеты отправляешь 1,2,3 фото.

Comment: А как ты пробовал решить эту проблему?

Comment: Добавил в саму бд 3 строки вместо одной, photo1, photo2... В коде пробовал добавить строку  print(message.photo[-1].file_id) - не помогло, бот нужен для моего магазина, из меня кодер так себе

Comment: Может столбцы, а не строки? Вообще, медиагруппы это несколько сообщений с медиа. Но у них всех есть одинаковый параметр media_group_id. Можно ждать файлы с media_group_id, собирать в словарь, а потом записывать в БД. Либо можно можно написать 3 хендлера, которые будут обрабатывать 3 фото и писать их в БД. А вообще, если из вас кодер так себе, может лучше такую доработку заказать у фрилансеров?